# A WP plugin specifically to manage an organization’s membership

Tags: wordpress

There are any number of membership plugins for Wordpress that exist to monetize website content. People pay a subscription and have access to pages and posts. This makes it difficult to locate what I am looking for.

**Is there a plugin that is specifically for managing the membership in an organization?**

**WHAT IT SHOULD DO**

- Have the ability to import existing
  membership details and create WP
  users from those details.
- Automate and manage the
  collection of annual dues.
- Facilitate mass e-mails to members.
- Restrict access to some of the Web site pages
  perhaps by linking membership to WP
  roles.
- Perhaps manage payments for conferences.
- Have the ability to export membership details.

**SOME THINGS IT SHOULD NOT DO**

- Have pay per post functionality.
- Sell value added pages.
- Have different levels of accounts based on content.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a similar plugin for a non-profit organization client of mine, and finally found MemberMouse. I was particularly concerned about being able to setup annual dues at a certain time of the year with pro-rating for new members during the rest of the year.  While this is not in their base plugin, they can custom program that for a small fee.

The only parts of your request that plugin may not cover is facilitating mass emails (you could manage that through something like Constant Contact) and taking payments for conferences (which you could setup on your site anyway pretty easily using PayPal or your merchant account provider and a cart).

Hope this helps. I would suggest contacting MemberMouse with your questions to see if it will work for you.